# Reactjs router exact doesn't work and override other route components to current route

Tags: reactjs, path, react-router-dom, render

I used 'exact' but when DataConfirmation component renders then Login component is also rendering.

in Login.js:

```
<Router>
       <div>
           <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/DataConfirmation">
                     <DataConfirmation/>
                </Route>
           </Switch>
           <Link to="/DataConfirmation">
                <Button type="submit">
                      Login
                </Button>
           </Link>
       </div>
</Router>
```

in DataConfirmation.js:

```
<Router>
       <div>
           <Switch>
                <Route exact path={"/"}>
                     <Login/>
                </Route>
                <Route path={"/HomeSearch"}>
                     <HomeSearch/>
                </Route>
           </Switch>
           <Link to={"/"}>
                <Button type="submit">
                      Change phone number
                </Button>
           </Link>
           <Link to={"/HomeSearch"}>
                <Button type="submit">
                      verify
                </Button>
           </Link>
       </div>
</Router>
```

**I'm new to reactjs, thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

You are using two separate routing contexts. This means that nested router that `Login` is rendering is handling *its* nested `Switch` and `Route` components in isolation from the outer router.

Remove all nested routers, you need only one router per app to provide a routing context, and as you have found out, you want ***all*** your routing components to use the ***same*** routing context.

Within the `Switch` component, route path order and specificity matters, order the routes in descending order of path specificity, i.e. from the more specific paths to less specific paths. When the paths are ordered correctly there is nearly no need for the `exact` prop. Now all paths can match as path prefixes for any nested routes that may be rendered.

You will want to **not** exactly match on the `"/"` path that `Login` is rendered on so the nested `Switch` and routes and be properly matched. It seems there is a circular dependency between `Login` rendering the route for `DataConfirmation` and `DataConfirmation` rendering the route for `Login`, so I'll just assume at this point one of these is a typo and that your routing is generally structured as you like and is working.

Login

```
<div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/DataConfirmation">
      <DataConfirmation/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
  <Link to="/DataConfirmation">
    <Button type="submit">
      Login
    </Button>
  </Link>
</div>
```

DataConfirmation

```
<div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/HomeSearch">
      <HomeSearch/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <Login/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
  <Link to="/">
    <Button type="submit">
      Change phone number
    </Button>
  </Link>
  <Link to="/HomeSearch">
    <Button type="submit">
      verify
    </Button>
  </Link>
</div>
```